# Can't resume after suspend?

Tags: linux, systemd, boot, opensuse, thinkpad

Recently (after a system update, I believe), my laptop stopped resuming after a suspend from closing my laptop lid. Usually, when I open my lid after suspending it, I'll  see a black screen with my cursor and nothing else. I'm not able to move the cursor, and I'm not able to open a tty terminal using the keyboard. This doesn't happen all the time, but I haven't been able to find any pattern to when it does and does not happen.

Looking through the journalctl log from the last time this happened, there's no signals being sent after I open the lid again. The log from the time I closed the lid until I shut down my laptop again is pasted below.

```
Jan 31 11:57:30 whiteboard kwin_x11[2134]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 8 (BadMatch), sequence: 42342, resource id: 60817415, major code: 42 (SetInputFocus), minor code: 0
Jan 31 11:57:30 whiteboard kwin_x11[2134]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 42489, resource id: 60817961, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
Jan 31 11:57:30 whiteboard kwin_x11[2134]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 42525, resource id: 46138526, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard systemd-logind[1326]: Lid closed.
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard org_kde_powerdevil[2302]: powerdevil: Suspend session triggered with QMap(("Explicit", QVariant(bool, true))("Type", QVariant(uint, 1)))
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard org_kde_powerdevil[2302]: powerdevil: Suspend session triggered with QMap(("Explicit", QVariant(bool, true))("SkipFade", QVariant(bool, true))("Type", QVariant(uint, 1)))
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard org_kde_powerdevil[2302]: powerdevil: Starting Login1 suspend job
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard org_kde_powerdevil[2302]: powerdevil: Pausing all media players before suspending
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard kdeinit5[1991]: bluedevil: About to suspend
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: lock called
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard NetworkManager[1473]: <info>  [1548961054.9755] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard NetworkManager[1473]: <info>  [1548961054.9758] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: Lock window Id:  23068678
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 23068678
Jan 31 11:57:34 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 23068680
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 60817412
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard kscreenlocker_greet[4307]: Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard NetworkManager[1473]: <info>  [1548961055.1785] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 60817416
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard kernel: e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 60817424
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 60817429
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard kscreenlocker_greet[4307]: Icon theme "ubuntu-mono-dark" not found.
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard kscreenlocker_greet[4307]: Icon theme "gnome" not found.
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 60817431
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 60817433
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: MapNotify: 60817431
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 60817435
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard kscreenlocker_greet[4307]: UdevQt: unable to create udev monitor connection
Jan 31 11:57:35 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: CreateNotify: 60817444
Jan 31 11:57:36 whiteboard kscreenlocker_greet[4307]: Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
Jan 31 11:57:37 whiteboard ksmserver[2059]: MapNotify: 23068678
Jan 31 11:57:37 whiteboard systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jan 31 11:57:37 whiteboard systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jan 31 11:57:37 whiteboard systemd-sleep[4318]: INFO: Skip running /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/grub2.sleep for suspend
Jan 31 11:57:37 whiteboard systemd-sleep[4318]: Suspending system...
```

This is on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, kernel version `4.20.2-1-default`.